# Combobox component for Swift (failed with DownPicker)

Tags: swift, combobox, picker

I need a component like comboBox when it dropes down and allow user to select value. PickerView looks terrible and one I found nice looking was [DownPicker](https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker)

I followed instructions, installed it and tried to use but I did not see the data I pass to this component in it.

```
let data = NSMutableArray()
        data.addObject("1")
        data.addObject("2")
        data.addObject("3")

        let a = DownPicker(textField: group!, withData: data)
```

Also nothing happens when I tap down arrow icon

[image]

Just advice me another components like this one which will work correctly with xcode 7 beta 6 or help me to fix problems with current try. Thanks)

Update:
I've just tried [this](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) one. Nothing good from it too :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DownPicker is working fine with Swift. I just tried it and use it in my project. The problem I see is that you init DownPicker to local variable. There are two ways how you can use DownPicker in your project and it looks you choose Control Wrapper. So you should have in your controller these controls:

```
@IBOutlet weak var personTextField: UITextField!
var personDownPicker: DownPicker!
```

The first one is outlet connected to UITextField added in storyboard. DownPicker I Initialized in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let persons: NSMutableArray = ["Architect", "Designer"]
        self.personDownPicker = DownPicker(textField: self.personTextField, withData:persons)
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering how this should be in swift 3, just change the array line to: `let persons = ["Architect", "Designer"]`