# No such module 'DownPicker' Cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

All the other similar  questions did not solve my problem.So I decided to ask my own . I have opened the xcworkspace file correctly . Here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'WashAndShine' do

pod ‘DownPicker’,git : https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker

end

target 'WashAndShineTests' do

end

target 'WashAndShineUITests' do

end
```

My Link Binary with Libraries :
[image]

Here is my bridging header file , I don't know how to import the .m file.Is that the problem?

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

#import "DownPicker.h"
//#import "DownPicker.m"
#import "UIDownPicker.h"
//#import "UIDownPicker.m"
#endif /* Header_h */
```

But it still says no such module even after building ? Have I done anything wrong? Tried reinstalling it but still same thing . The only thing that might cause it to fail in my opinion is Downpicker is written in objective C. but from this post [Combobox component for Swift (failed with DownPicker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427823/combobox-component-for-swift-failed-with-downpicker) it looks like it does work on Swift.

Comment: You don't have to import *.m files - they are supplementary to *.h files. Does it tell the error is in the bridging header? P.S. make sure you checked out all the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there

Comment: A lot of libraries are giving this error when you try to import them twice: once in your bridging header and another time in the file with actual code.

Comment: @Michael Fixed the problem . I can instantiate objects from objective C classes but I cannot use import DownPicker at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import it in your swift bridging header file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

and define your header file here to xcode [image]